# Get a value based on defined order

Tags: c#, .net

I currently have data in db table as follows:

```
Data in table 
Desc       Value                                                                                                 
BNo        12 
CNo        Null 
ANo        15 
DNo        Null 
ENo        15
```

If ANo is blank i need to display BNo. If BNo is blank then display CNo on form. Once i found a non null value based on a defined priority order of DESC(In this case A-E), i need to exit my method. How can this be implemented,i can hard code desc names based on priority but it am looking to implement in a more optimized way. Any advices please.

Comment: Can you provide more details? All I can suggest is alphabetical ordering.

Comment: Ok in my code i need to define a order of display. For instance i define it as ANo,BNo,CNo etc., Now i need to fetch db values get my defined priority and check which first one does not have null value. Then take that value into consideration. In my example ANo is 15 so dont look at other values.

Comment: Are you using ADo.NET or EF? What have you tried so far?

Comment: Iam using ADO.NET. I tried using string comparsion and able to get it but it does not optimized.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It sounds like you have the means to order the list, as you state "in a priority order".  Not sure what this priority is but for the example let's assume it is in alphabetical order by "Desc".  And let's also assume (for simplicity) that these values are in a dictionary.  Given this you can write a Linq statement as such...

```
dict.OrderBy(o => o.Key).FirstOrDefault(d => d != null);
```

eg...

```
Dictionary<string,string> dict = new Dictionary<string,string>();
dict.Add("BNo", "12");
dict.Add("CNo", null);
dict.Add("ANo", null);
dict.Add("DNo", null);
dict.Add("ENo", "16");

Debug.WriteLine(dict.OrderBy(o => o.Key).FirstOrDefault(d => d.Value != null));
```

This will return the first non-null value.  If all values are null then null is returned.

There may be some incorrect assumptions here but the OrderBy and FirstOrDefault should be able to be used in whatever manner necessary to achieve your goal.  The only things that should need to change is the "o.Key" and "d.Value" to reference your actual properties.
For example, if this information is in a class such as this...

```
class Info
{
    public string Desc { get; set; }
    public int? Number { get; set; }
}
```

and you have a list of these such as...

```
List<Info> info = new List<Info>();
```

then you could write...

```
var returnValue = info.OrderBy(o => o.Desc).FirstOrDefault(d => d.Number.HasValue);
```

Comment: I tried to implement this way but the problem is i cant use order by. My type desc values are as follows. Landline,Mobile,Fax, Email. So i want this to be a predefined order and check for values based on this order.

Comment: I created a custom dictionary with Priority code and values. Then used your linq which is returning expected value. Thanks for the help.

Answer (score 1):

SQL Server

```
select top 1 *
from MyTable
where Value is not null
order by [Desc]
```

MySQL:

```
select *
from MyTable
where `Value` is not null
order by `Desc`
limit 1
```

Answer (score 0):

Are ANo, BNo, CNo, etc values of the Desc field in the table, or are Desc, ANo, BNo.. etc fields in the table. I get this doubt because you just that these are actually contact details.
If it is the first, RedFilter gave you an answer.
If it is the second, a dynamic query can be an option. 
Just add the fields in the order of priority to an array, and iterate to build the query.